# how to remove java.lang.numberformatexception: invalid double: ""

Tags: android

I have a method to get all the items in the database, but I don't know what is the problem, it always say java.lang.numberformatexception: invalid double: "". Any help would be highly appreciated.

My code:

```
@Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            productList = new JsonConverter<Products>().toArrayList(s, Products.class);
            BindDictionary dic = new BindDictionary();

            dic.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Products>() {
                @Override
                public String getStringValue(Products item, int position) {
                    return item.name;
                }
            });
            dic.addStringField(R.id.tvDesc, new StringExtractor<Products>() {
                @Override
                public String getStringValue(Products item, int position) {
                    return item.description;
                }
            }).visibilityIfNull(View.GONE);

            dic.addStringField(R.id.tvPrice, new StringExtractor<Products>(){

                @Override
                public String getStringValue(Products item, int position) {
                    return ""+item.price;

                    //return String.valueOf(item.price);
                }
            });

            dic.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImage, new StringExtractor<Products>() {
                @Override
                public String getStringValue(Products item, int position) {
                    return item.img_url;
                }
            }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
                @Override
                public void loadImage(String url, ImageView img) {
                    //Set image
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, img);
                }
            });

        }
```

**Products.java**

public class Products implements Serializable {

```
@SerializedName("itemID")
public int id;

@SerializedName("productName")
public String name;

@SerializedName("descrt")
public String description;

@SerializedName("price")
public double price;

@SerializedName("my_img")
public String img_url;
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is not the relavent code for exception, you are not using double any where

Comment: what do you mean? i really don't know what is the reason of that problem

Comment: Could you share the Products.java

Comment: are you converting any value to double ?

Comment: I think, i have nothing to conver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error because of your Products.java

There is a  double type property in your Products.java that called price,

When you convert the json object to java object the both types must be same. In your case,

you get a

```
{ 
 ...
 price:"",
 ....
}
```

in your json object. But the java side, it waits for double value. You could send price:0.0 instead of price:"" or write your own converter.

Comment: i will put 0.0 on that blank qoute?

Comment: Yes on the JSON side, change blank qoute to 0.0 Because the price variable is not a string.

Comment: You can generate your pojo object via http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ link. Just paste your JSON example, It'll generate java object for you

Answer (score 1):

first see the datatype for price which you want to send.i also faced same situation long back i resolved it by passing data what is expected or before sending data parse the data to required type.

```
  @Override
            public double getStringValue(Products item, int position) {
                return ""+item.price;

                //return String.valueOf(item.price);
            }
```

Comment: in price you returning string value parse that string to double you problem will be solved

Comment: how sir can you help me please.

Comment: please add complete pojo class i will see and i will provide needful solution

Comment: build pojo based on json raw data using json schema to pojo converter copy the output pojo created based on json raw data so that depending on data type it takes you have to pass that value